# Proving the following about sets of propositions.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm wondering how proving  this question.If $\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2 \vdash \bot$ then there exists a proposition such that $\Gamma_1\vdash A$ and $\Gamma_2 \vdash \lnot A$.I tried some idea.for instance we know that if $\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2 \vdash \bot $ then there exists a finite set of propositions $\Delta$ that is subset of $\Gamma_1\cup \Gamma_2$ and $\Delta \vdash \bot$ and so there exists $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ and $A$ such that $\Delta_1 \cup \Delta_2 =\Delta$ and $\Delta_1\vdash A$ and $\Delta_2 \vdash \lnot A$ now it's enough to prove that for example $\Delta_1 \subset \Gamma_1$ and $\Delta_2 \subset \Gamma_2$ but I don't see this.I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you use $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ iff $\Gamma \vDash \phi$ ?

Comment: @Bram28: How do you prove $\bot$ from $\neg P$ and $\neg P$?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes I know this theory,but how is it applicable here?

Comment: @Bram: Then set $A=\neg P$ and you get $\Gamma_1\vdash A$ and $\Gamma_2 = \neg A$. It always holds that $A\vdash \neg\neg A$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes of course  .. I kept thinking $A$ had to be atomic ...

Comment: @MAh2014 I thought $A$ had to be atomic ... which would have made for a harder problem, for which formal semantics might have been easier to work with.

Comment: @Bram28: Much harder indeed: Even with your proposed fix, the property then would still not be true for $\Gamma_1=\{P\lor Q\}$ and $\Gamma_2=\{\neg P, \neg Q\}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm :) Yes, *much* harder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done.

For the last short step, let $A$ be the conjunction of the finitely many elements of $\Delta_1$.

Comment: I can't see how to prove that $\Gamma \vdash \land(\Delta_1)$ ,isn't it needed to first prove $\Delta_1 \subset \Gamma_1$?

Comment: @MAh2014: Isn't that how you defined $\Delta_1$? If not, then how did you split $\Delta$ into $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$?

Comment: I just deduce that there  exists $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ but how could we be sure that $\Delta_1 \subset \Gamma_1$,I think it could be not!

Comment: @MAh2014 $\Delta_1$ is whatever sentences you use from $\Gamma_1$ that you use in the deduction of $\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2 \vdash \bot$, so this is always a subset of $\Gamma_1$. In the extreme case that you didn't use anysentences from $\Gamma_1$ at all, i.e. where $\Delta_1 = \{ \}$, just set $A = \top$.

Comment: Fine,but I can't prove that $\Gamma_2 \vdash \lnot \land\Delta_1$,sorry i just learnt the topic, I'm not so innovative in it.

Comment: @MAh2014: Assume $\Delta_1$ and derive a contradiction. (The precise details of this will depend on which kind of proof system you're working in, which you have not revealed).

Comment: I use natural deduction system.

Comment: @MAh2014: What kind of rule does the variant of natural deduction you're using have for concluding something of the form $\neg\varphi$?

Comment: the rule if$\Gamma , A \vdash \bot$ then $\Gamma \vdash  \lnot A$.

Comment: @MAh2014: Okay, so if you want to apply that, then you need to have $\Delta_2, {\land}\Delta_1 \vdash \bot$. Does that remind you of anything?

Comment: Now that I typed the rule I got the answer ,Thank you for teaching me step by step.:)